# checking if a string has specific words and fetching a word from sentence in objective C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, nsstring

NSString *word = @"Tomorrow is monday select white car";

I want to check if the string has "select" and "car" then i want to get the color of the car. Here user can write "select blue car" "select red car", i just want to get the color after checking if string has select and car.
Thanks

Comment: -1 for not bothering to read the spec for NSString.

Answer (score 1):

Just check to see if the word `@"select"` is in the string, and if it is, grab the substring.

```
if([word rangeOfString:@"select"].location != NSNotFound){
  // Grab the next substring after the word @"select";
}
```

Hope that Helps!

Comment: i also want to make sure that it also has car in the string. i think i can check for two strings in a nsstring and take the middle substring.

Comment: Exactly. You can use the above code to check for any string you like!

Comment: This doesn't handle cases of misspelling or where select is a substring of other words like selected selection selecting deselect etc.

Comment: Also, color names in English can be very arbitrary. You're going to need a long list of words that might be colors.

Comment: What if a user enters a very different grammatically correct sentence?

Comment: His question is not to use semantic parsing analysis, which is WAY beyond what he actually needs. He is asking for a specific case. There is no need to make it that complex.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
if([string1 rangeOfString:@"select"].location != NSNotFound && [string1 rangeOfString:@"car"].location){

NSLog(@"select and car found");
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i have done same thing but now i have to make a subsstring of color.
I tried this
 NSString *removeString= @"select";
            NSRange range = [value rangeOfString:removeString];
            NSInteger idx = range.location + range.length;
            NSString *szResult = [value substringFromIndex:idx];
but this was giving me all the words after select, i want to get only next word after select.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *word = @"Tomorrow is monday select white car";
if (([word rangeOfString:@"select"].location)&& ([word rangeOfString:@"car"].location)  != NSNotFound ) {
    NSLog(@"string contains select and car!");
} else {
    NSLog(@"string does not contain select and car!");
}
```